# Problems creating an object using a class and then putting it on a array

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to do a `User` class and then trying to do an array for it
however every time I create a student it don't add to the array.
I tried to change names etc but its really a problem in code.

```
public class UsersList {

    User student;
    User[] studentList = new User[49];

    public UsersList() {
    }

    public void createUser(int userNumber) {
        String numberToString = String.valueOf(userNumber);
        if (numberToString.length() == 9) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
                if (studentList[i] == null) {
                    studentList[i] = new User(userNumber);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
public class User {
    public int userNumber;
    private boolean isolation;
    private String state;

    public User(int number) {
        userNumber = number;
        isolation = false;
    }
}
```

If someone can help me I would be greatful.

Comment: Do you call method `createUser` with an input argument containing exactly 9 digits to match the condition of `if` statement?  That is, `userNumber` should be between `100_000_000` and `999_999_999`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following simple test method to `UsersList` class to demonstrate that the code is fine and you need to provide appropriate `userNumber` value when calling `createUser` method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UsersList list = new UsersList();

    int userNumber = 1;
    
    list.createUser(userNumber); // insufficient length
    
    System.out.printf("all nulls for %d? %s%n", userNumber, Arrays.stream(list.studentList).filter(Objects::isNull).count() == list.studentList.length);
    
    userNumber = 123_456_789;
    list.createUser(userNumber); // length of the number is 9
    
    System.out.printf("no nulls for %d? %s%n", userNumber, Arrays.stream(list.studentList).filter(Objects::nonNull).count() == list.studentList.length);
    
}
```

Output:

```
all nulls for 1? true
no nulls for 123456789? true
```

---

However, you may want also to initialize the instance variable `student`.